# Using CompareTool on Mac

Tags: macos, itext7

Is there a way / what's the way to use CompareTool on a Mac?

(How) can Ghostscript and ImageMagick be configured to work in this environment?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You can download the latest version of GhostScript from http://pages.uoregon.edu/koch/

Locate the "GhostScript xx.xx" link with the highest "xx.xx" version number - it's usually near the top of the page - and click on it. This will start the download of the GhostScript PKG (Package Installer). How the download actually happens is dependant on your browser and system set-up, and thus outside the scope of this article.

Once the PKG has downloaded, open the folder it was downloaded to (this is usually "Downloads" within your own Home folder).

Double click the PKG icon and follow the on-screen instructions. Accept the defaults if you don't know what to change.

Once the process has finished, GhostScript should be installed and ready for action.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/) or [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/) which custom builds GhostScript and ImageMagick in your environment. Download MacPorts or Homebrew and type:

```
sudo port install ghostscript ImageMagick
```

or

```
brew install ghostscript ImageMagick
```

The `port` or `brew` command downloads GhostScript and ImageMagick and many of their delegate libraries (e.g. JPEG, PNG, Freetype, etc.) and configures, builds, and installs GhostScript and ImageMagick automagically.

I tried this out for myself with Homebrew on a MacBook Air, the MacPorts part I got from googling.